# Angular BehaviorSubject not updating in time

Tags: angular

i followed a tutorial on how to create a full Angular + JWT Authentication ( here is the link in case of need [Angular 8 - JWT Authentication Example & Tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/22/angular-8-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial?fbclid=IwAR1nIcQWvyN6z4nrTe3QNQCIhVX1SWx4tiS2pV9BrLmYfx0QY3Wsqg5Sck8)  ).
so after setting up the whole project and when i tried to test it i had some problems .
When i log in i need to send the response of the api to the AuthGuard via an BehaviorSubject object so i can notify him that i am connected and i can go to the next page but the problem is that the BehaviorSubject object is not updating its value instantly so i need to do the log in process twice so it works fine , i didn't know how to solve this problem even though i followed completely the tutorial .
ill show you my files :

my authentication serivce :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class AuthenticationService {

 private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<Dinosaure>;
 public currentUser: Observable<Dinosaure>;

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
            this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Dinosaure> 
                  (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
            this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();

                   }

        logIn(dinosaure) {
             return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/dinosaure/login`, dinosaure)
               .pipe(map(res => {
                     localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(res));
                 //this.currentSubject.next(res) does not update the new value the first time i log 
       in and then it works fine the second time i log in 
                     this.currentUserSubject.next(res);
                     return res;
                     }));
                }

              public get currentUserValue(): Dinosaure {

                  return this.currentUserSubject.value;
                  }
```

this is my AuthGuard :

```
     @Injectable({
         providedIn: 'root'
           })
       export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
       constructor(private router: Router,
       private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
             ) {
            }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

        // this.authenticationService.currentUserValue returns null the first time i log in and then it's full when i login a second time 
      const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
     if (currentUser) {

    return true;
   }
this.router.navigate(['/']);
return false;
 }

 }
```

my login function in the login component :

```
onClickLogin() {
if (this.loginForm.valid) {
  const dinosaure = this.loginForm.value;
  this.dinosaure = {
    ...this.dinosaure,
    login: dinosaure.login,
    password: dinosaure.password
  };

  this.as.logIn(this.dinosaure).subscribe(data => {
    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
  });
}
```

}

Comment: I think it is just your guard is evaluated too early, In that case it would work exactly as you describe

Comment: @Andrei the problem is that a friend of mine have the same code and it works for him fine , but in my case what do u think i need to do , it's been a while i didn't work with angular so i literally forgot everything

Comment: could you provide a piece of code where the `logIn` method is called?

Comment: @Andrei sure thing ill added in my post

Comment: i would like to see the piece of code that calls `logIn`, not the implementation

Comment: @Andrei i updated my post you can check it

Comment: Can you create a project on Stackblitz with your code?

Comment: @bjdose i really never used stackblitz but i can push it to a github project if you want

Comment: Sure, that way I can replicate the problem and help you

Comment: @bjdose here : https://github.com/slim-aouadi/test-appartoo-front

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized on your project available here: github.com/slim-aouadi/test-appartoo-front that you have added AuthenticationService into multiple modules, but also you have added the property providedIn: 'root'.

You have to remove AuthenticationService from all the modules and that's all. Why? Because you are creating multiple instances.

**Edited:**

I found AuthenticationService added into the array providers of AppModule and LoginComponent.

AppModule.ts

```js
... code omitted
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouteModuleRoutingModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule

  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BasicAuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },

    // provider used to create fake backend
    AuthenticationService // <==== Remove it
  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

LoginComponent.ts

```js
... code omitted
import { Dinosaure } from 'src/entities/dinosaure';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [AuthenticationService] // <==== Remove it
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
... code omitted
}
```

You need to remove AuthenticationService because of this service has the 'provided in' property with 'root'.

> From Angular 6 there is now a new, recommended, way to register a provider, directly inside the @Injectable() decorator, using the new providedIn attribute. It accepts 'root' as a value or any module of your application. When you use 'root', your injectable will be registered as a singleton in the application, and you don’t need to add it to the providers of the root module. Similarly, if you use providedIn: UsersModule, the injectable is registered as a provider of the UsersModule without adding it to the providers of the module." - https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/05/04/what-is-new-angular-6/

Comment: i only called AuthenticationService in login component just to use the service i don't recall using it in another module , can u share with me where did you find it ?

Comment: can u please be more specific about what you mean by added AuthenticationService into multiple modules

Comment: i wanted to ask you if i'am going to remove all the imports of AuthenticationService from the other components then how am i going to use the functions in that service

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer. Now it is more explicative.

Comment: omg ! man i don't know how to thank you ! for real i was struggling so hard to solve this problem and u just solved it for me , thank you a lot and i appreciate your help and sorry if i annoyed you !

Comment: Don't worry! You're very welcome, I'm glad to hear it